# Extend pylab.poly1d in my plot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am plotting a graph and using the `pylab.poly1d` function to plot the line of best fit. But the best fit line isn't long enough. How can I extend this line. Here is my code:

```
y=np.genfromtxt('_02total.txt').T[0] 
x=np.genfromtxt('_02total.txt').T[1] 
fit=pl.polyfit(x,y,1)
fit_fn=pl.poly1d(fit)
scat=pl.plot(x,y, 'yo', x, fit_fn(x), '--k')
pl.show()
```

How do I make the `fit_fn` line longer?

#### EDIT:

Second attempt doesn't work

```
y=np.genfromtxt('_02total.txt').T[0] #unweighted
x=np.genfromtxt('_02total.txt').T[1] #weighted
fit=pl.polyfit(x,y,1)
fit_fn=pl.poly1d(fit)
x_min=0.2
x_max=2
n=1000
x_fit = pl.linspace(x_min, x_max, n) 
y_fit = fit_fn(x_fit)
scat=pl.plot(x,y, 'yo', x, fit_fn(x), '-r' )
```

Comment: You should use `scat=pl.plot(x,y, 'yo', x_fit, y_fit, '-r')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# Fit function given by:
fit_fn=pl.poly1d(fit)

x_fit = pl.linspace(x_min, x_max, n) 
y_fit = fit_fn(x_fit)
```

`x_min` and `x_max` specify the limits where you wish to plot the data, `n` the number of points. You should *always* do this when fitting data as the number of points in `x` is probably quite course (hence why you are fitting for it).